# Real-time handling of multiple files in data processing (Python Multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The program is monitoring a folder `received_dir` and process the files received in real time. After processing the file, the original file should be deleted to save the disk space.
I am trying to use `Python` `multiprocessing` and `Pool`.
I want to check if there is any technical flaw in current approach.

One of the problem in the current code is that the program should wait until all 20 files in the queue are processed before starting the next round, so it may be inefficient in certain conditions (i.e, various file sizes).

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import os.path

Parse_OUT="/opt/out/"
Receive_Dir="/opt/receive/"

def parser(infile):
    out_dir=date_of(filename)
    if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
        os.mkdir(out_dir)

    fout=gzip.open(out_dir+'/'+filename+'csv.gz','wb')
    with gzip.open(infile) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            data=line.split(',')
            fout.write(data)
    fout.close()
    os.remove(infile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool=Pool(20)
    while True:
        targets=glob.glob(Receive_Dir)[:10]
        pool.map(parser, targets)
    pool.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues:

1. `if not os.path.exists(out_dir): os.mkdir(out_dir)`: This is a race condition. If two workers try to create the same directory at the same time, one will raise an exception. Don't do the if condition. Simply call `os.makedirs(out_dir, exist_ok=True)`
2. Don't assemble file paths with string addition. Simply do `os.path.join(out_dir, filename+'csv.gz')`. This is cleaner and has fewer failure states
3. Instead of spinning in your while True-loop even if no new directories appear, you can use the inotify mechanism on Linux to monitor the directory for changes. That would only wake your process if there is actually anything to do. Check out pyinotify: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify
4. Since you mentioned that you are dissatisfied with the batching: You can use `pool.apply_async` to start new operations as they become available. Your main loop doesn't do anything with the results, so you can just "fire and forget"
5. Incidentally, why are you starting a pool with 20 workers and then you just launch 10 directory operations at once?

Comment: I want to split the output folder by date. `receive_dir` does not change, but depending on the date in the filename, it splits the output folder in the next day.

Comment: @notilas doesn't matter. If receive_dir does not exist before the start of your parser function, you have a race condition with a possible exception. And if it always exists, you don't need to put that check and makedir call into the parser function to begin with. The other solution to this issue is to just put the makedirs call into main, not parser.